# How to apply custom style on tab view

Tags: android, tabview

How to apply custom style on tab view like button in android. I used selector on button but not getting proper way to show tab click event.

Comment: Thanks @bpAFree for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set different background when tab is selected or unselected

you can get help from here -

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: Thanks Ashish Agrawal for link. surely I will try with it.

Comment: it works but as per requirement i find this link http://droidista.blogspot.in/2012/12/styling-tab-selectors-for.html  suits my requirements. Thakns for sharing link.